# Did I find counter-example to "function continuous iff inverse image of every closed set is a closed set"

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In "The Way of Analysis, Revised Edition - Jones and Bartlett" we have the following exercise:

> p125: 
>   Excercise 1: Let $f$ be a function defined on a closed domain.
>   Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if the inverse image of every
>   closed set is a closed set.

I am stuck at the example of function of which I claim is not continuous, but is defined on a closed domain and the inverse image of every
closed set is a closed set. See the picture below. Could anybody help me out confirming / debunking if my counter-example is indeed a counter-example?

[image]

Comment: Compute the inverse image of $[{3 \over 2},2]$. It is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your counter example has a problem.

Find the inverse image of $[1, 3/2]$

The answer is not closed.

We have three components,$$ [1,a]\cup(c,d]\cup[e,2]$$ and the middle one is not closed.